# in my springboot application i have a nested object, if i run a JPQL query, it does not execute ORDER BY in the correct way

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jpql

in my SpringBoot application i'm using jpa and hibernate.
I have an entity class named workPosition, it has an int id, a Set<Effort>, a Set<Project> and a String name
every effort has an Employee, and a Date named date,
the Employee entity has an int id and a String surname
the Project entity has an id

in the jpaRepository<workPosition,Integer> i have this query

```
SELECT wp FROM workPosition wp " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH wp.effort effort " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH wp.project P " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH effort.employee emp  " +
        "WHERE wp.P.id = ?1 AND effort.dataEffort BETWEEN ?2 AND ?3 " +
        "ORDER BY wp.name ASC,emp.surname ASC, effort.dataEffort ASC
```

?1 = id of the project
?2 date of start

?3 date of end

but i get as result a list of workPosition named by name, but the nested objects of type Effort are not ordered by date and surname of the Employee, their position is random every time i call the service... why? how can i fix it?

i tryed changing the order of my predicates in the ORDER BY but that did not change anything